# Noun for someone whose secret has been discovered?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

Is there a one-word noun for someone who has been lying or keeping a secret, but who has been found out?

I can think of descriptors that aren’t nouns (*exposed, found out*, etc.) but I’m looking for a noun that means the actual person who has been exposed or found out, etc.

Comment: [Perhaps](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4732/word-for-disrespecting-eldest-half-sister-by-referring-to-her-husband-as-girly-g#comment15959_4732).

Comment: Wouldn't the "been found out" require a verb? Please give us context. How do you intend to use this word?

Comment: Grzelefaneache happens to have that exact meaning. Lucky you!

Comment: Someone who has been found to be a liar is **bewrayed**.    'Bewrayer'(noun) for the person who exposes but I found no evidence of 'bewaryee', or the person exposed 
  [1]: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/bewray

Comment: [Ex](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/ex).

Comment: Beware the bewrayed.

Comment: I agree with @ThirdNews: the word *bewrayed,* though not a noun, fits perfectly.

Comment: *bewray* doesn't seem to convey *found out* at all.  It applies to a breach of confidence, not detection.

Answer (score 9):

*Fraud* comes to mind.

> To our dismay we discovered Jacob was a fraud.

I say *fraud* because it almost always is used in the context of someone who has been exposed.

Answer (score 3):

Wouldn't they just be a *liar*?  If they are not found out they are not a liar (to you).

Comment: Indeed! They would be a 'liar *in flagrante delicto*'; as opposed to being a common or garden 'liar'.

Answer (score 2):

***Debunked*** might fit.

It is usually used as a verb or an adjective. It can be used as an adjectival noun also but that usage is not common. (For example: debunking the debunked.)

***[Debunker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debunker)*** is the one who debunks.

In a very few sources, ***debunkee*** is used as a neologism or a nonce word for the one who gets debunked.

---

***[debunk](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/debunk)***

> : to expose the sham or falseness of
>
> : to show that something (such as a belief or theory) is not true : to show the falseness of (a story, idea, statement, etc.)

---

*[Disclosed](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Disclosed)* comes to mind also but it is used as an adjective mainly.

> made known (especially something secret or concealed); *"the disclosed purpose of their wicked plan"*

---

**Note:** Of course they can be called many things like crook, sham, phoney, double-dealer, counterfeiter, faker, scammer, fraudulent, trickster etc.  depending on the context but the key point is being found out/discovered.

Comment: Google Books says there are [about 57 written instances](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22debunkee%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) of ***debunkee***, at least a couple of them going back to the 1930s. It certainly sounds good to me for "person whose lies have been exposed".

Comment: It's no big deal, but I don't think I'd use the word "neologism" for such an obvious and regularly-formed derivation that obviously *has* been used repeatedly over decades.

Comment: I suppose in some contexts the usage might be sarcastic and/or "tongue-in-cheek", but the very first instance in my link is a guy writing about classical music (specifically, Handel) in 1947. It seems completely serious and unselfconscious to me... [Now, debunking generally means that the debunker attempts to knock the **debunkee** off a pedestal to which he, the debunker, considers that he, the **debunkee**, has no right.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22debunkee+off+a+pedestal%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). (You can also see why he seriously ***needs*** the word in that context! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers when I clicked on your Google books link, the results were only 20!?

Comment: @Mari-Lou: Well I did write *"Google **says**..."*. It still says 57 on the first page (of an expected 3 pages) when I go there. When I go to the next page, it says there should be 62, but when I go to the *third* page there's only one more result left to show, and GB is finally forced to admit there are only 21 in total. Their "guestimate" algorithm could do with some tweaking, obviously.

Comment: @FumbleFingers What does OED say about debunkee?

Comment: "Slowly, slowly catchee debunkee".

Comment: @Mari-Lou: As you might expect, OED say nothing. But they don't even mention ***abscondee*** - which is much more common than ***debunkee***, but actually totally unnecessary. Inflected forms can reasonably be considered valid words if they are regularly derived and easily understood. Dictionaries don't need to list them to prove they "exist".

Answer (score 2):

While the finding out of the lie isn't a requirement, the word **charlatan** is probably appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

If that person was under oath when he/she lied and was debunked later on, the usual, legal term is [**perjurer**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/perjurer).

> **perjury**: the crime of telling a lie in a court of law after promising to tell the truth.

Alternately, consider *impostor* for someone who has been lying about or keeping his or her real name, identity, etc., a secret until he or she was debunked, and [**discoveree**](http://www.andthevalleyshook.com/2009/5/19/879732/should-coaches-turn-in-other) for someone who has been found out as lying, cheating, or keeping a secret.

> [**impostor**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/impostor): a person who practices deception under an assumed character, identity, or name.
>
> [**discoveree**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/discoveree): (*rare*) one who is discovered.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply apply a couple of the world's most famous proper names to this situation?

"Nixon" or "Clinton" both scream to me as exceptional options, as in:

> "He certainly has proven to be a Nixon."
>
> "After that Clinton I doubt I'll ever believe him again."

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is word for what you've described.

Someone who has been lying is a liar, but that applies whether the lie has been discovered or not.  The same applies to fraud, charlatan, or perjurer.  I agree that these words are most often applied to people whose lies have been discovered, but that's because we don't call people liars unless we know they've lied.  (For the same reason I don't refer to a box-of-kittens as a box-of-kittens until I've opened the box and seen the kittens inside, though it has been a box-of-kittens all along.)

But the original question is not referring to only liars.  It refers also to someone who has kept a secret.  Keeping a secret isn't the same as lying, and someone who has kept a secret isn't necessarily a liar or a fraud.  (In the sense that my doctor is not a liar because he refuses to discuss my medical condition with you.)

Comment: Right--I keep running into trouble because I don't want something quite so negative, or that indicates the lying/keeping of secrets is habitual.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I can't think of one word that specifically means that. If you mean someone who is known to lie in general, the common phrase is "known liar". If you mean that he has been caught lying about one particular thing, I don't know any word or short phrase for that. You'd pretty much have to say, "Senator Jones was caught lying about his campaign contributors" or whatever the story is.

Answer (score 0):

**Culprit**: a person who is responsible for a crime or other misdeed.
"the car's front nearside door had been smashed in but the culprits had fled"

```
...the cause of a problem or defect: "low-level ozone pollution is the real culprit"
```

Google: Define culprit

Answer (score -1):

Consider:

**Racketeer**

**Liar**

**Hypocrite**